# как посчитать чекбосы в колонке таблицы и записать значения в value у input

Tags: javascript, jquery

мне необходимо подсчитывать количество чекбоксов в колонке и выводить их в value у input

Comment: и заголовок тоже переведите, пожалуйста. и уберите английский дубликат, пожалуйста.

Comment: Думаю что можно было бы сделать подсчет по каждой колонке отдельно, но тоже не нашла такого решения. Т.е задать селектор колонке и в границе этого селектора считать чекбосы, так вывод был бы проще, но как это сделать ? И как потом адаптировать это вместе с not done

Comment: Здесь только русскоязычная аудитория. Англоязычная на другом сайте. У вас есть возможность как то разметить ваши чек боксы?

Comment: Я поняла, наверняка в аккаунтах запуталась :D. Крайне извиняюсь.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так это можно сделать

```js
var nulls = document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox");
[...nulls].forEach(function (el) {
  el.value = 0;
});


$("#tblRootCauseBody").on("change", "input[type=checkbox]", function () {
  var index = $(this).closest("td").index() - 1;
  var znak = this.checked ? 1 : -1
  if (index) {
    nulls[index - 1].value = Number(nulls[index - 1].value) + znak;
  } else {
    [...nulls].forEach(e => e.value = Number(e.value) - 1)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" id="tblRootCauseBody">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Not done</th>
            <th>Param1</th>
            <th>Param2</th>
            <th>Param3</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Reeves</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>


          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Reeves</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>


          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Reeves</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Reeves</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Reeves</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Reeves</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
    <td>Count checked</td>
    <TD></TD>
    <td class="count_cheked" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
      <input name="{TOTAL_SW}" id="TOTAL_SW" type="text" size="10"
                                                      maxlength="2" value="" class="checkbox"/>
        <label class="btn" for="modal-TOTAL_SW" data-field="TOTAL_SW">
            <div id="error-TOTAL_SW" class="divError"><span title="Input rules">?</span></div>
        </label></td>
    <td class="count_cheked" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
      <input name="{TOTAL_P}" id="TOTAL_P" type="text" size="10" maxlength="2"
                                                      value="" class="checkbox"/>
        <label class="btn" for="modal-TOTAL_P" data-field="TOTAL_P]">
            <div id="error-TOTAL_L" class="divError"><span title="Input rules">?</span></div>
        </label></td>
    <td class="count_cheked" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
      <input name="{TOTAL_L}" id="TOTAL_L" type="text" size="10" maxlength="2"
                                                      value="" class="checkbox"/>
        <label class="btn" for="modal-TOTAL_L" data-field="TOTAL_L">
            <div id="error-TOTAL_L" class="divError"><span title="Input rules">?</span></div>
        </label></td>
</tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Comment: @darina7 Допустим в итого 0, ставим not done - остается 0. А потом жмем на галочку, что должно происходить, какое значие? 0 или 1. Но в целом все можно сделать, нужно только детально логику расписать. Попробуйте самостоятельно эту логику прописать. Не будет получаться, создайте новый вопрос с вашими попытками и детализацией

Comment: @darina7 Записываются, иначе не выводились бы данные. Или про какие именно value идет речь?

Comment: @darina7 Да, уйдут.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1490507/Помогите-дописать-сценарии-условий-к-чекбоксам-в-таблице